# Stripe setting payment description for subscription

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

I've successfully created a stripe subscription plan.
When payment arrives under subscription plan it's Description field states - 'Subscription Creation'
I want it to state - 'Subscription Payment'.
How can i do this?

Comment: Before asking question, it may be beneficial to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the various pages in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to change the description at the time of subscription creation. I think the best way to make this happen would be to listen for `invoice.created` webhook events and check if the invoice belongs to a subscription (also optionally you can take a look at the `billing_reason` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason) on the invoice).

You can only edit the invoices when they're in `draft` mode so you'll probably have an hour to update the invoice description by calling the API [endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/update#update_invoice-description) with the description you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by updating the intent immediately after the subscription success.
Still, it would be better if I could setup the intent before the subscription.

```
  subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create(subscriptionParams);
            const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.id);
            const paymentIntentNew = await stripe.paymentIntents.update(
                paymentIntent.id,
                {description:'Subscription intent edit'}
              );
```